# In what sequence should I play Baldur's Gate, Icewind Dale and Planescape Torment so I can transfer my character?

Tags: baldurs-gate, planescape-torment, icewind-dale

A friend suggested I should checkout the old school DnD games. Now I want to play through:

- Baldur's Gate I + Tales of the Sword Coast
- Baldur's Gate II + Throne of Bhaal
- Icewind Dale I + Heart of Winter + Trials of the Luremaster
- Icewind Dale II
- Planescape Torment

What is the right sequence and is it possible to transfer my "original" character when I finish with the previous game?

I want to have the illusion that my virtual character lives through each of those adventures.

Comment: Thanks to have asked this question. I guess you bought the whole series on gog like I did :-)

Comment: Just play the BG series. Skip the rest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not possible to transfer a character between the various series. While you can and should go from BG1 to BG2 (And I'd highly recommend using a mod such as Tutu, or the newer Enhanced Edition to take advantage of BG2s more powerful and flexible character creation for BG1),  Icewind Dale II uses a different variant of the D&D rules (3rd edition to BGs/IWD's 2nd), and Torment relies on your character being The Nameless One, with a very specific history and set of skills.

The closest you might be able to come is using character editing tools like Dalekeeper to alter an IWD character at the start of that game - but since you will finish BG2 in high epic levels, that would render IWD... somewhat less than fun or challenging.

As far as a gameplay order; play the various series in sequence, but beyond that, it shouldn't matter too much. Do note that Torment plays somewhat fast and loose with rules that you might become used to from the other titles (it's not complex, but it is different), and as noted, IWD2 uses 3rd Edition, which is *very* different.

Comment: Thanks. Would you still recommend any particular order?

Comment: @Ayckoster not really. Play BG1 before 2. Other than that, these titles have very little to do with each other in a narrative sense. They just share a rule set. (And in the case of BG/IWD, a world, but the games have as much in common as a pair of stories set in Italy and Alaska.)

Comment: Icewind Dale and Baldur's Gate are both regions on the Sword Coast, so more like Alaska and Oregon, but still, your point stands.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but

I recommend playing **Icewind Dale 2** first, it uses the most advanced rules and you get to take advantage of better features. its a fun game and its shorter then the *Baldurs Gate saga*.

After that you will probably want to play **Icewind Dale 1** to experience that story as well.  The two games are set in different times with different characters.

After that try some of the older games. play **Baldurs Gate 1** before you play 2 though since you can use the same character and start 2 at the level you finished 1 at.

And last I would play **Planescape** since its not even in the forgotten realms setting and its an older game as well as being turn-based and not combat intensive like the other games. its more like *Ultima* or something, you have to go around and answer questions and find clues. also it's the oldest of the games so it has the worst graphics, but they say the story is great.

Comment: This answer is wrong in some particulars. Planescape is neither turn based nor older than Baldur's Gate 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Play the **Baldur's Gate** series (BG1, BG2, ToB) first. No question.  It is a mega classic for a reason and BG2 especially is a gem.  You can carry-through with the same character and it is worth doing so.
2. If you liked the combat elements of Baldur's Gate, and want more of that at the expense of branching storylines and dialog, then play **Icewind Dale 1** (if you want to stay in the 2e ruleset) or **Icewind Dale 2** (if you want to use the 3e ruleset).  If, on the other hand, you liked the lore, dialog, and NPC interaction of Baldur's Gate then play **Planescape Torment**.
3. Play whichever one you didn't play in step 2.